# cors jquery withCredentials cookie

Tags: cookies, cors

client:

```
$.support.cors = true;

// ajax option
beforeSend: function (XHR) {
  XHR.withCredentials = true;
  XHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + base.accessToken);
}
```

I use "fiddler" and catch the request, it shows no cookie included.

AuthN server has set cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, preflight requests won't be sent with the cookie, it's just used to check wteather server api support CORS. So maybe you can close authentication of your server for OPTIONS methods

Answer (score 0):

$.support.cors = true;

it is enough.

server side needs to add 'AccessControlAllowCredentials' httpheader.